# resetting a session query variable

Tags: coldfusion

Looking for some pointers to resetting a session query Variable in coldfusion.

I'm currently implementing a lock account after 10 tries to a login form and I'm struggling to reset the number of failed tries once a user successfully logs in.

```
public function getLoginFails(required String Username, required String App){
  
   getLoginFailsQuery = new Query();
   getLoginFailsQuery.setDatasource(this.datasource)
   getLoginFailsQuery.addParam(username)
   getLoginFailsQuery.addParam(ip)
   getLoginFailsQuery.addParam(application)
   getLoginFailsQuery.setSQL(data inserted into db)

   session.numFails = getloginFailsQuery.execute().getResult();

   if(session.numFails.count < 10){
     return session.numFails.count;
   }else if(session.numFails.count == 10){
       run a query to update accountLocked to = 1; 
   }
}
```

The above part works fine (I know some stuff is missing from the addparams() etc. It updates to 1 if 10 attempts and stores the tries in a session. [session variable showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8vw3.png)

My issues is resetting the variable when a successful login has occurred.

session.numFails.count = 0 doesn't work, am I missing something?

Comment: Does that variable get used after a successful login?  If not, why bother trying to update it at all?

Comment: Also, it is better to use simple values than keeping query results in `session`.